# Using dd and an sdcard

Tags: boot, system-installation, dd

I had Ubuntu 14.04 running sweetly however when installing an IMG to an SD card for a raspberry pi like so:

```
dd bs=4M if=2014-06-20-wheezy-raspbian.img of=/dev/mmcblk0
```

My beloved Ubuntu now boots like so:

```
BusyBox v1.18.5 (Ubuntu 1:1.18.5-1ubuntu4) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands. (initramfs)
```

Have I just made a major mistake and dd over the filesystem on the HDD ? Is there a fix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of three things could be happening here (I'm not too familiar with Raspian):

#### The SD card is interfering with the boot sequence

It's possible that for some reason the boot process is picking up the partitions/files on the SD card and causing it to fail booting, try simply removing the SD card and reboot. I believe that should do the trick, if not you might have some trouble.

#### You fried your partition

If that command that you have above is the actual command you used, there shouldn't have been a problem. However, if you instead typed something along the lines of `of=/dev/sdX#` or `of=/dev/sdX`, then that would have friend the beginning of the partition number # or the beginning of the disk respectively.

If you did, in fact, somehow manage to fry your partition, then there's really not a lot you can do to recover the data aside from using a tool like `testdisk` (which may or may not work depending on whether all backup superblocks were wiped) or, worst case, `scalpel` to recover the files. Otherwise, simply reformat and try again.

`dd` can potentially be a very destructive program. It has no warnings that would tell you "Hey buddy, are you *really* sure you want to do this? It's probably a bad idea" -- it just goes. Therefore, you need to be sure that the command you type is the command you really want. For example, you might ensure that /dev/mmcblk is the correct device by first mounting the SD card (or a partition on it) and then finding the device listed in the `mount` command. However, from the command you typed it should have worked as expected...

#### There is an error in the boot sequence

I've seen this happen while creating custom ISOs and it tends to happen when the root filesystem can't be found (or it's corrupted). If you have a separate /home partition, then there still may be problem with with the root partition while your /home partition remained untouched.

As described [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelBoot), remove the kernel options `quiet` and `splash` and append the kernel option `debug` while in GRUB (the bootloader). To do this, press <kbd>E</kbd> while you have a boot option selected. Once the line is edited, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to boot.

This will write a /tmp/initramfs.debug file. After the system fails to boot, you can then use the `httpd` command to allow another computer to access the filesystem via a browser, or you can simply reboot with a LiveCD and examine the file. What you may be looking for is a line that says something similar to "Unable to find root partition."

It is also possible that the root filesystem is corrupt and needs to be fixed with a filesystem check. In order to do this, first boot from a LiveCD/USB.

1. Open a console
2. Find the partition in question using `gparted-pkexec`. If you suddenly have a big block of free space on your drive, it's very possible that the root partition got overwritten and may not be recoverable. If that's not the case, continue to step 3.
3. `e2fsck -p /dev/sdX#` (where /dev/sdX# is the device and partition of your root filesystem (possibly /dev/sda4 or /dev/sda5, but you you'll want to verify that with `gparted-pkexec` from the LiveCD/USB)

Comment: Well i had encrypted the home partition so sda5 is fine and on boot up im still required authenticate it.

Comment: I should add i put the computer in sleep mode all night and powered up fine the next day sleep. Was only when i shut down and restarted the issue occurred.

Comment: Perhaps it was just a failed driver update? Perhaps it doesn't have anything to do with your 'dd' at all? Did you try selecting a different kernel at startup? A driver may have updated and failed to install for some reason possibly.

Comment: thats my feeling but i don't know how to test it as none of the older kernals do any different.

Comment: I updated my answer to include initramfs debugging as well as a FS check.

Comment: Hi, no free space so i guess thats a good sign. I have drive /dev/sda.  /dev/sda2 extended and a sub one /dev/sda5 crypt-luks.

Comment: Turns out its some corruption of ext4 journalling i think from bad sectors on the hdd. Got the data back in the end though but 8h headache later. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Good to hear! Thanks for the accepted answer. If you've got some disk issues, check the -c option of e2fsck. It checks for bad spots on the disk and adds them to the badblocks inode preventing them from being written to later and causing future problems. It will take a long time and will have to be done while in a LiveCD/USB environment, but it should be worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the issue here is that you tried flashing it without mounting, make sure the path is /mnt/ or /media/, so you are sure you have mounted properly.

If I were you I would use a GUI for this sort of thing.

Comment: You don't need to mount when using `dd`. In fact, it's a Bad Idea™ that can lead to data corruption due to the fact that the FS doesn't see what's going on at the block level.

Comment: I definitely unmounted it